# Jquery on wordpress still loading in header

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have WordPress 3.9 running on local (MampPro) and below a portion of functions.php 
containing the code to load jquery and other js in the footer.
The problem is that I am getting jquery to be loaded twice. One in the header and one in the footer. I am a bit confused to figure out why!

```
<?php
/**
* Enqueue JS - http://eamann.com/tech/dont-dequeue-wordpress-jquery/
*/

function zero_script() {
    if (!is_admin()) {

        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        //wp_register_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/js/lib/modernizr-    2.7.0.min.js', array(), null, false);
        wp_register_script('main_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/js/main.min.js',   array('jquery'), '', true);

        //wp_enqueue_script('modernizr');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', '', '', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'main_js' );

    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'zero_script'); // initiate the function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

****SOLVED*****

I am building a WP Theme from scratch and the only plugin installed is "iThemes Security"
with checked the option:

> 

"Enqueue a safe version of jQuery" 
Remove the existing jQuery version used and replace it with a safe version (the version that comes default with WordPress).

It was burried in all the options...I have unchecked that option and now I have jquery called once, in the footer.
The First jquery call (in head was called by IThemes and the second in the footer from me)
I did some amend to the file so it is more clear what is happening:

```
<?php
/**
* Enqueue JS - http://eamann.com/tech/dont-dequeue-wordpress-jquery/
*/

function zero_script() {

 if (!is_admin()) {

  //Call Modernizr
  //wp_register_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/dist/js/lib/modernizr-custom.min.js', array(), null, false);
  //wp_enqueue_script('modernizr');

  //Call JQuery
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  wp_register_script( 'jquery', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', '', '', true);
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );


  //Call Custom js file
  wp_register_script('main_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/js/main.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
  wp_enqueue_script( 'main_js' );

 }

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'zero_script'); // Initiate the function
```

Comment: Aha, nice one dude. Though the wordpress heads over at wordpress stack say deregistering is a bad idea, because plugin developers base their plugins on the core version of wordpress. If I was you I would remove the deregister, register and enqueue of jquery. Just let "main_js" depend on jquery with `array("jquery")` like you already have, with `true` at the end. This will load jquery just the same, it's how it should be done and saves you 3 lines of code :) but up to you.

Comment: Also, I believe you're just deregistering the same core wordpress jquery and registering it again, so it's pretty pointless.

Comment: Hi dude, the post linked on top is related with the practice to deregister worpress version of jquery and register a new one, usually from google cdn....what I am doing is using a trick to call the wp version of jquery in the footer. If you click on the jquery path you can see that is the minified version that WP is using. So when you upgrade WP if they update their JQuery version you get for free the most updated one...and it is up to the plugin's developer to update their plugin with the latest WP Jquery version

Comment: Usually I use one or two jquery plugins handcrafted in the code so It is up to me to update them, so they can work with the latest version of JQuery

Comment: on the other side using WP jQuery version you don't have to lose your mind trying to understand wich version of JQuery a particular plugin needs at time.....

Answer (score 1):

Try taking out `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );`

EDIT: try changing
`wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', '', '', true );`

to

`wp_register_script( 'jquery', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', '', '', true );`

and keep

`wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );`

Okay EDIT2:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script( 'jquery', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', '', '', true );
wp_register_script('main_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/js/main.min.js',   array('jquery'), '', true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'main_js' );
```

Edit:3

```
function zero_script() {
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script( 'jquery', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', '', '', true );
if (!is_admin()) {
wp_register_script('main_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/js/main.min.js',   array('jquery'), '', true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'main_js' );
}
}
```

Comment: See edit :) replace your code with my edit in that exact order. If it doesn't work I'm at a loss :)

Comment: By any chance does the second jquery say `jquery-migrate.min`? if so just `wp_deregister_script('jquery-migrate.min');`

Comment: <script type='text/javascript' src='http://zero/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'></script> Same in header and footer..;(

Comment: Last go, try my edit 3, and make sure you're not registering jquery anywhere else or another script is dependant on jquery and being loaded in the header and make sure yo double check the php page and you're not linking directly calling it in the head there.

Comment: No Luck, Dude..I am starting to build this theme from zero..so there are no plugins involved and the only part in the header.php is <?php wp_head(); ?>

Comment: Strange, I have a custom theme and I just used my edit 3 and it works and it's only getting called once, in the footer.

Comment: I posted your question in the wordpress chat stackexchange hopefully one of them might be able to help, if you haven't fixed it. Good luck.

Comment: Have you tried just removing the deregestering, registering and enqueueing of jquery altogether? If `main_js` is registered and you declare it depends on jquery, like you have done already, should load wordpress' core jquery automatically.

Answer (score 1):

you are calling it twice.............

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', '', '', true );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

you just need

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

as wordpress has jquery ready to be used :)